# Jquery child element links

Tags: jquery

I am using the following function to create a simple accordion. The problem is that the final tier that opens contains links. These links inherit the click function from their parents and therefore don't function correctly as links. Any ideas on how to avoid this? Ta

```
jQuery('.loc_level_1').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).children('.level_2').slideToggle('200');
    return false; // this prevents event bubbling 
});
```

Comment: You should include your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand - it seems you wrote the solution to your problem already :)

However, it would be more elegant to just do:

```
jQuery('.loc_level_1').click(function(event){
    jQuery(this).children('.level_2').slideToggle('200');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this method works but now it adds the link url to the end of the existing URL?

Comment: That means that your links probably don't start with protocol (`http://` or some other)... **Also**, if `.loc_level_1` is actually `<A>` I would suggest doing `event.preventDefault()` as well...

Answer (score 0):

Adding a handler to the links and stopping propagation from there should work:

```
jQuery('.level_2 a').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/f8PRF/

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
jQuery('> .loc_level_1').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).children('.level_2').slideToggle('200');
    return false; // this prevents event bubbling 
});
```

The ">" means "only select immediate children, not children-of-children".